# Adding custom validation across multiple questions within a block on Qualtrics

Tags: jquery, survey, qualtrics

I have a block of 12 questions in Qualtrics. The order of the questions is randomised. For each question, participants are forced to select either `upvote`, `downvote`, or `pass`.

*How can I force participants to select each of the possible options exactly 4 times across the 12 questions?*

In other words, each participant must choose 4 questions to `upvote` and choose 4 other questions to `downvote`.

---

My thinking is to have embedded data fields (e.g., `upvoteCount` and `downvoteCount`), increment these data fields +1 each time the corresponding answer option is clicked, and to disable the next button for the block until these embedded data fields both equal 4. However I'm struggling to implement this.